# I want to get rid of all white spaces from my website in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get rid of all white spaces from my website in html , the more I move my text to the right the more the space whitespace it creates on the right side of the page. Like you see in the photos there are a lot of whitespaces I suspect it is the elements creating these spaces , can someone tell me how to get rid of it . if anyone can help me please do so.

```css
.btn_earnmoney {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 350px;
    left: 710px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
  }

  .Balance_Text {
    font-size: 150%;
    position: relative;
    top: -800px;
    left: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f1dd84;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .Background_img {
    /* non available image replaced with dummy image */
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300x300/d936d9/000000&text=some+background+image");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f1dd84;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>BuzzMoney</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn_earnmoney" onclick="button_pressed()">
  <!-- non available image replaced with dummy image -->
  <img class="Image_of_btn" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/a6ff00/000000&text=earn+money" alt="EARN MONEY" height="100px" width="100px" />
  </button>
  <button class="btn_withdraw" onclick="withdraw_button_pressed_()"> </button>
  <div class="Background_img"></div>
  <p class="Balance_Text" id="Balance">0 $</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="earnmoney.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="disableRightClick.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: here on the top is a lot of white space]

Comment: `top: -800px;` on `.Balance_Text` is probably the culprit

Comment: @evolutionxbox beat me to it - although  I'd also suggest putting the background image on the `body`, rather than a random `div` halfway down the page.

Comment: You should wrap the div with bg image and the paragraph onto another div, and use position absolute/relative. than use top:0px on <p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>BuzzMoney</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn_earnmoney" onclick="button_pressed()">
  <!-- non available image replaced with dummy image -->
  <img class="Image_of_btn" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/a6ff00/000000&text=earn+money" alt="EARN MONEY" height="100px" width="100px" />
  </button>
  <button class="btn_withdraw" onclick="withdraw_button_pressed_()"> </button>
  <p class="Balance_Text" id="Balance">0 $</p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="earnmoney.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="disableRightClick.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
  background-image: url("yourUrlHere");
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}
```

You can find those properties for the background in this [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) link

Comment: But i still have space to the right of my webpage how to fix?